# simple derivative question at a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Use the limit process to find the slope of the graph of the function at the specified point.
$f(x) = 3x − 2x^2,    (3, −9)$

I found $$Msec = \frac{(3(3+h)-2(3+h)^2-9)}{h}
=\frac{-2h^2+9h+18}{h}.$$ Where do I go from here?

Comment: Please try to use MathJax for formatting your questions. See a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

You have a few little sign mistakes in your calculation. The equation should be
$$\frac{3(3+h)-2(3+h)^2+9}{h}\frac{-2h^2-9h}{h}$$
which you can write as
$$\frac{-2h-9}{1} = -2h-9 \to -9 \ (h \to 0)$$
So the answer is $-9$.